# What type of encryption is used with Mirai?

Tags: c, encryption

I cannot figure this out.
It uses a key to encrypt and when the key is changed the output is completely different. It's pretty genius.
However, I have the key that is used, I just do not know how to decrypt it.
So, if someone could put a name to this method of encryption and/or tell me how to decrypt strings compiled with it, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    static uint32_t table_key = 0xdedefbaf; // here is the key
    void *x(void *, int);
    int main(int argc, char **args)
    {
        void *data;
        int len, i;
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            printf("Usage: %s <string> <data>\n", args[0]);
            return 0;
        }
        if (strcmp(args[1], "string") == 0)
        {
            data = args[2];
            len = strlen(args[2]) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unknown data type `%s`!\n", args[1]);
            return -1;
        }
        printf("XOR'ing %d bytes of data...\n", len);
        data = x(data, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("\\x%02X", ((unsigned char *)data)[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    void *x(void *_buf, int len)
    {
        unsigned char *buf = (char *)_buf, *out = malloc(len);
        int i;
        uint8_t k1 = table_key & 0xff,
                k2 = (table_key >> 8) & 0xff,
                k3 = (table_key >> 16) & 0xff,
                k4 = (table_key >> 24) & 0xff;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            char tmp = buf[i] ^ k1;
            tmp ^= k2;
            tmp ^= k3;
            tmp ^= k4;
            out[i] = tmp;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you find this bit of source code? I'm looking at this repo of Mirai https://github.com/jgamblin/Mirai-Source-Code I got from Wikipedia but can't seem to find this file. This is interesting to study!

Answer (score 1):

This is a symmetric encryption, it just XORs every byte of the input string with the four bytes of the key. To decrypt it you need to run the output as input.

Example:

```
./sotest string "dies ist ein test"
XOR'ing 18 bytes of data...
\x30\x3D\x31\x27\x74\x3D\x27\x20\x74\x31\x3D\x3A\x74\x20\x31\x27\x20\x54
```

If you translate that hexadecimal representation of the bytes with `echo -e` you get

```
echo -e "\x30\x3D\x31\x27\x74\x3D\x27\x20\x74\x31\x3D\x3A\x74\x20\x31\x27\x20\x54"
0=1't=' t1=:t 1' T
```

Run that through the program and get

```
./sotest string "0=1't=' t1=:t 1' T"
XOR'ing 19 bytes of data...
\x64\x69\x65\x73\x20\x69\x73\x74\x20\x65\x69\x6E\x20\x74\x65\x73\x74\x00\x54
```

(We have one byte more now, we found a bug.)
Running `echo -e` with that input results in

```
echo -e "\x64\x69\x65\x73\x20\x69\x73\x74\x20\x65\x69\x6E\x20\x74\x65\x73\x74\x00\x54"
dies ist ein testT
```

Das NUL-byte `\x00` ends a C-string but this is not a C-string hence the trailing `T`.